# How to pick the smallest value in a list when an iterative process is applied to the list

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration

I need to find the smallest value in a series of lists. I understand the code for the smallest value in just one list:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print (min(x))  
1
```

Simple enough. However, I would like to know if there is a way to write code that finds the smallest value for each list I have without stopping and adjusting the code (whether by an iterative process or some other means). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to find the minimum of each list in a list of lists?

Comment: How are you storing your lists? Are they all separate, ex. `x = [...]`, `y = [...]`, `z = [...]`; or are they all in one big list of lists, ex. `lists = [[...], [...], [...]]`?

Comment: I just want the minimum value for each list. I don't need to compile all of the minimum values together into a new list, strange as that may sound.

Comment: The lists are all separate.

Comment: @oahmed31: You can compile them into a list of lists and then use any one of the answers below.

Comment: "I just want the minimum value for each list. I don't need to compile all of the minimum values together into a new list" <- so what do you want? Just print the minimum values?

Comment: @timegb Sorry, I definitely was not clear on what I was asking. I am using ArcGIS ModelBuilder and an iterative process was used to select features according to their location (eg. lease coordinates, etc). As a result, I am only accessing one list (in this case, the values are well depths) at a time. Obviously, as the iterator is run in ModelBuilder, the list and its values change. What I would like to know is how to write a code that finds the smallest value in a list given that the iterator essentially changes the values in said list. Again, sorry for not being clear before.

Comment: And what's the problem with `print(min(lst))` each time `lst` has changed?

Comment: @timegb Ah, there isn't. I misunderstood what the code did. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a list of lists out of your separate lists. For example, if you have lists `A`, `B` and `C`, the list of lists would be `[A,B,C]`.

Now, to get a list of all the minimum values for each list in a list of lists `lst`:

```
[min(x) for x in lst]
```

To get the global minimum:

```
min(x for sublist in lst for x in sublist)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [min(x) for x in lst]
[1, 4, 7]
>>> min(x for sublist in lst for x in sublist)
1
```

---

Edit in reaction to OP's comment:

> I just want the minimum value for each list. I don't need to compile all of the minimum values together into a new list

If you just want to print the minimum values for each list `A`, `B`, `C`, ... , you can do:

```
for lst in (A,B,C): # put as many lists as you like into the parentheses
    print(min(lst))
```

---

Edit in reaction to

> I am only accessing one list (in this case, the values are well depths) at a time. [..] What I would like to know is how to write a code that finds the smallest value in a list given that the iterator essentially changes the values in said list.

Just `print(min(lst))` each time `lst` has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got a list of lists, this should do it:

```
minimums = [min(l) for l in lists]
```